# How to replace more than one value in a python list?

Tags: python, list

Im on the road to get familiar with python an tried to create a hangman game for the start.
I want to check if the guessed character is in the word and then get the position via index and replace a "_" in the list i created for the hidden word so its slowly builds up.
But if a letter is more than once in a word it only works for the first position.

```
            # retrieve the guessed char and set it as a variable
            guess = input()
            # check if chosen word contains the guessed char if yes -> print the char and a message
            if guess in wordList:
                print(guess + " is correct!")
                # set i to the position of the guessed char
                i = wordList.index(guess)
                # replace an underscore with the correct char on the same position as in wordList
                hiddenWord[i] = guess
                # show the updated hiddenWord
                print(hiddenWord)`
```

Word is: "dad"
input = d
output:

```
['d', '_', '_']
```

output I want:

```
['d', '_', 'd']
```

value of i is 0, do I need to get something like 0,2?

Comment: You have to iterate over the entire list to find every match; `index` only returns the *first* of multiple matches.

Comment: `[guess if c==guess else "_" for c in wordList]`

Comment: @not_speshal That will overwite all previous correct guesses. What's needed is something more like: `[w if guess == w else h for w, h in zip(wordList, hiddenWord)]` or `[guess if guess == wordList[i] else hiddenWord[i] for i in range(len(wordList))]`.